# Difference of two vectors and maintain order

Tags: matlab, vector

Given two vectors `A = [ 1 7 3 2 8 9 4 6 5 ]` and  `B = [ 2 4 6 8 ]`, and I want to remove the elements of B from A, so that I get a vector `[ 1 7 3 9 5 ]`, how can I do this in Matlab R2011b while retaining the order of the vector?

I've looked at `setdiff`, but the resulting vector is sorted (or not sorted as a set is).

Comment: Huh... that simple. That's it! If you put that as an answer, I can mark is as right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`ismember`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to get the matching ones and then negate to get the non-matching ones and then finally index into `A` -

```
 A(~ismember(A,B))
```

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Matlab you can do that with [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) using the `'stable'` option, which preserves order:

```
setdiff(A,B,'stable')
```

Comment: I didn't bother looking at `setdiff` until now, might be useful!

Comment: For the purposes of anyone else looking for an answer, I updated my question to say I'm using R2011b, so I don't have the 'stable' flag unfortunately. :-\